# Center Alignment text in WebView?

Tags: android, webview

How can Fix this I use Webview and set a backgroundResource, How can Center the text inside the webView?

This is my xml code

```
 <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="10sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="81dp" />
```

[image]

Comment: :try to use `gravity`

Comment: I already do that android:gravity="center" but nothings happen :(

Comment: where do you get this text from?

Comment: have you use 'layoutgravity' ?

Comment: so you are setting a text to a textview

Comment: Better to set alignment in your htmlscript..

Comment: Instead of using background image, include this image in the response it self and load it using webview. This way, you can make it work for any device and in any orientation.. Use image in your HTML code itslef.

Comment: Use templets image in your HTML code using <img src=""/> tag.

Comment: @Dimitrr yes I set a text in textview and the problem is alignment :(

Comment: @YuDroid can you give sample syntax for that <img src=?> in android? Thanks :)

Comment: Refer this link. Here using style sheet you can set your background image and text : http://www.html.am/html-codes/background-code/background-repeat.cfm

Comment: @YuDroid Can you add my code using src tags? refers to my Comment below this comment, Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="This is Textview.This is Textview.This is Textview.This is Textview.This is Textview.This is Textview.This is Textview.This is Textview.This is Textview." />
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

use this and set the visibility through activity